# How to remove a word prefix using grep?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

How can I remove the beginning of a word using grep? For example, I have a file that contains this:

```
www.abc.com
```

I only need the this part:

```
abc.com
```

Sorry for the basic question, but I have no experience with Linux.

Comment: Use [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-5) instead of grep.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't edit strings with `grep` in Unix shell, `grep` is usually used to find or remove some lines from the text. You'd rather use `sed` instead:

```
$ echo www.example.com | sed 's/^[^\.]\+\.//'
example.com
```

You'll need to learn regular expressions [to use it effectively](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Sed can also edit file in-place (modify the file), if you pass `-i` argument, but be careful, you can easily lose data if you write the wrong `sed` command and use `-i` flag.

### An example

From your comments guess you have a TeX document, and your want to remove the first part of all .com domain names. If it is your document `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
www.example.com
example.com www.another.domain.com
\end{document}
```

then you can transform it with this `sed` command (redirect output to file or edit in-place with `-i`):

```
$ sed 's/\([a-z0-9-]\+\.\)\(\([a-z0-9-]\+\.\)\+com\)/\2/gi' test.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
example.com
example.com another.domain.com
\end{document}
```

Please note that:

- A common sequence of allowed symbols followed by a dot is matched by `[a-z0-9-]\+\.`
- I used groups in the regular expression (parts of it within `\(` and `\)`) to indicate the first and the second part of the URL, and I replace the entire match with its second group (`\2` in the substitution pattern)
- The domain should be at least 3rd level .com domain (every `\+` repition means at least one match)
- The search is case insensitive (`i` flag in the end)
- It can do more than match per line (`g` flag in the end)

Comment: The URLs are saved in a file. So my command will be: grep'\.com$' source.text >dest.tex | sed 's/^[^\.]\+\.//' ?? It gives me error ??

Comment: I also need to write the names (they are many lines not one) in another text file after removing www.

Comment: I tried to guess what's your task and wrote an example of a `sed` regex to edit domain names in the document, without touching the rest of the lines. If your problem is different you may need a different regex, but overall the idea is the same.

Comment: Normally you either redirect to file (`> dest.tex`), or just use pipe (`| sed ...`), but not both. You don't need `grep` if you want to change some lines but keep the rest. A carefully written regex and `sed` is probably all you need.

Comment: On macOS, the `sed` command does not work the same as the Linux version. But you could use this simpler version on the Mac, without regular expressions: `echo www.example.com | sed "s/www.//"`  -- It will replace `"www."` with empty string `""`.

Answer (score 10):

As the others have noted, `grep` is not well suited for this task, `sed` is a good option, or if the text is well ordered a simple `cut` might be easier to type:

```
echo www.abc.com | cut -d. -f2-
```

- `-d.` tells `cut` to use `.` as a delimiter.
- `-f2-` tells `cut` to return field 2 to infinity.

Comment: Take a look here for more informations about `cut`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using `grep` easily:

```
$ echo www.google.com | grep -o '[^.]*\.com'
google.com
```

Instead of `echo` you must give your file.

```
$ grep -o '[^.]*\.com$' < file
```

I used here the regular expression '[^.]*.com'. That means: find me a word without `.` in it (`[^.]*`), after which goes `.com` (`\.com` in re). The `-o` key says that `grep` must show only that part that was found.

Answer (score 6):

## with grep's `--only-matching` and `\K`

You can do this with grep's `--only-matching` option:

```
echo 'www.abc.com' | grep --perl-regexp --only-matching 'www\.\K.*'
```

which can be shortened to

```
echo 'www.abc.com' | grep -Po 'www\.\K.*'
```

Both commands produce

> abc.com

with grep (GNU grep) 3.3.

Instead of `echo`, I'll use a [here string](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) to shorten the command further:

```
grep -Po 'www\.\K.*' <<< 'www.abc.com'
```

`\K` resets the starting point of the match, essentially forgetting the matched "www.". See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573920/what-does-k-mean-in-this-regex) for more on `\K`.

## with grep's positive lookbehind

You can also do this with a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
grep -Po '(?<=www\.).*' <<< 'www.abc.com'
```

## with awk's field separator `-F`

```
awk -F 'www\\.' '$2{print $2}' <<< 'www.abc.com'
```

This prints

> abc.com

The `$2{print $2}` part will print the second field if it's defined. This is necessary in case of multi-line input to avoid outputting blank lines for input lines that don't contain the field separator.

## with sed

```
sed --regexp-extended --quiet 's/www\.(.*)/\1/p' <<< 'www.abc.com'
```

The parentheses form a group which will capture everything after "www.". Using `\1` we reference that group and `/p` prints it.

The options `--regexp-extended` and `--quiet` have the shorter equivalents `-E` and `-n`:

```
sed -E -n 's/www\.(.*)/\1/p' <<< 'www.abc.com'
```

---

As noted by [Vladimir Nesterenco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15756358/vladimir-nesterenco) in a deleted answer, it's advisable to escape the dot with a backslash in all these regexes, to avoid matching strings that start with "www" followed by an *arbitrary character*, not only a dot. Otherwise, you'd extract "abc.com" from "wwwXabc.com", for example.

Depending on your input text, you might want to change the regex to make sure to only match occurrences of "www." *at the beginning of a line*:

```
^www\.
```

## with Bash' parameter expansion

If your input consists only of a single line, Bash' built-in [parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash) might be useful:

```
input="www.abc.com"; after=${input#"www."}; echo "$after"
```

If the input string doesn't start with "www.", this will print the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` is not used to manipulate/change text, only to search for text/patterns within text

You should look into something like `sed` or `awk` or `cut` if you want a command line tool to do it.  Or write a script in Python/Perl/Ruby/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this without invoking other programs, by using a builtin parameter expansion in bash:

```
while read line; do echo ${line#*.}; done < file
```

Where `#*.` tells the shell to remove the prefix that looks like 0 or more characters followed by a `.`.

You can view a cheatsheet with the different parameter expansions for bash here:

https://devhints.io/bash