# Remove a fixed prefix/suffix from a string in Bash

Tags: bash, replace, pattern-matching, string-interpolation

I want to remove the prefix/suffix from a string. For example, given:

```
string="hello-world"
prefix="hell"
suffix="ld"
```

How do I get the following result?

```
"o-wor"
```

Comment: Be very wary when linking to the so-called Advanced Bash Scripting Guide; it contains a mixture of good advice and terrible.

Answer (score 1212, accepted):

```
$ prefix="hell"
$ suffix="ld"
$ string="hello-world"
$ foo=${string#"$prefix"}
$ foo=${foo%"$suffix"}
$ echo "${foo}"
o-wor
```

This is documented in the [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) section of the manual:

> `${parameter#word}`
> `${parameter##word}`
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)). If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the `#` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `##` case) deleted. […]
>
> `${parameter%word}`
> `${parameter%%word}`
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)). If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the `%` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `%%` case) deleted. […]

Comment: Is there a way to combine the two in one line? I tried `${${string#prefix}%suffix}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @static_rtti No, unfortunately you cannot nest parameter substitution like this. I know, it's a shame.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth : the whole language is a shame, but it's so useful :)

Comment: @static_rtti , there is a workaround: echo `basename ${string/hell} ld` (where the grey part is between backticks)

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: The replacement is case sensitive. Any way to make it case insensitive?

Comment: @ccpizza Parameter substitution does not know such modifiers but if it's a fixed string you could always do e.g. `${foo#[Bb][Aa][Rr]}`. Not pretty but still possibly better than an unnecessary subshell/fork, depending on the situation.

Comment: OT: What @static_rtti wrote does work in ZSH using that exact syntax :-)

Comment: In case anyone is looking for it, escape with \ also works here, i.e. `${parameter%\[*\]}` will remove [any-string-here] suffix.

Answer (score 160):

Using sed:

```
$ echo "$string" | sed -e "s/^$prefix//" -e "s/$suffix$//"
o-wor
```

Within the sed command, the `^` character matches text beginning with `$prefix`, and the trailing `$` matches text ending with `$suffix`.

Adrian Frühwirth makes some good points in the comments below, but `sed` for this purpose can be very useful. The fact that the contents of $prefix and $suffix are interpreted by sed can be either good OR bad- as long as you pay attention, you should be fine. The beauty is, you can do something like this:

```
$ prefix='^.*ll'
$ suffix='ld$'
$ echo "$string" | sed -e "s/^$prefix//" -e "s/$suffix$//"
o-wor
```

which may be what you want, and is both fancier and more powerful than bash variable substitution. If you remember that with great power comes great responsibility (as Spiderman says), you should be fine.

A quick introduction to sed can be found at http://evc-cit.info/cit052/sed_tutorial.html

A note regarding the shell and its use of strings:

For the particular example given, the following would work as well:

```
$ echo $string | sed -e s/^$prefix// -e s/$suffix$//
```

...but only because:

1. echo doesn't care how many strings are in its argument list, and
2. There are no spaces in $prefix and $suffix

It's generally good practice to quote a string on the command line because even if it contains spaces it will be presented to the command as a single argument. We quote $prefix and $suffix for the same reason: each edit command to sed will be passed as one string. We use double quotes because they allow for variable interpolation; had we used single quotes the sed command would have gotten a literal `$prefix` and `$suffix` which is certainly not what we wanted.

Notice, too, my use of single quotes when setting the variables `prefix` and `suffix`. We certainly don't want anything in the strings to be interpreted, so we single quote them so no interpolation takes place. Again, it may not be necessary in this example but it's a very good habit to get into.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is bad advice for several reasons: 1) Unquoted, `$string` is subject to word splitting and globbing. 2) `$prefix` and `$suffix` can contain expressions that `sed` will interpret, e.g. regular expressions or the character used as delimiter which will break the whole command. 3) Calling `sed` two times is not necessary (you can `-e 's///' -e '///'` instead) and the pipe could also be avoided. For example, consider `string='./ *'` and/or `prefix='./'` and see it break horribly due to `1)` and `2)`.

Comment: Fun note: sed can take almost anything as a delimiter.  In my case, since I was parsing prefix-directories out of paths, I couldn't use `/`, so I used `sed "s#^$prefix##`, instead.  (Fragility: filenames can't contain `#`.  Since I control the files, we're safe, there.)

Comment: @Olie: As I understood your original comment, you were saying that the limitation of your choice to use `#` as sed's delimiter meant that you couldn't handle files containing that character.

Answer (score 30):

```
$ string="hello-world"
$ prefix="hell"
$ suffix="ld"

$ #remove "hell" from "hello-world" if "hell" is found at the beginning.
$ prefix_removed_string=${string/#$prefix}

$ #remove "ld" from "o-world" if "ld" is found at the end.
$ suffix_removed_String=${prefix_removed_string/%$suffix}
$ echo $suffix_removed_String
o-wor
```

## Notes:

#$prefix : adding # makes sure that substring "hell" is removed only if it is found in beginning.
%$suffix : adding % makes sure that substring "ld" is removed only if it is found in end.

Without these, the substrings "hell" and "ld" will get removed everywhere, even it is found in the middle.

Comment: Thanks for the Notes! qq: in your code example you also have a forward slash `/` right after the string, what is that for?

Comment: / separates the current string and the sub string. sub-string here is the suffix in th posted question.

Answer (score 25):

Do you know the length of your prefix and suffix? In your case:

```
result=$(echo $string | cut -c5- | rev | cut -c3- | rev)
```

Or more general:

```
result=$(echo $string | cut -c$((${#prefix}+1))- | rev | cut -c$((${#suffix}+1))- | rev)
```

But the [solution from Adrian Frühwirth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16623897/778533) is way cool! I didn't know about that!

Comment: This does not "remove the prefix/suffix", but does instead remove as many characters, which only matters if it's not certain that the string actually starts/ends with the pre-/suffix but is an important caveat about this solution to keep in mind.

Answer (score 22):

I use grep for removing prefixes from paths (which aren't handled well by `sed`):

```
echo "$input" | grep -oP "^$prefix\K.*"
```

`\K` removes from the match all the characters before it.

Comment: `grep -P` is a nonstandard extension. More power to you if it's supported on your platform, but this is dubious advice if your code needs to be reasonably portable.

Comment: @tripleee Indeed. But I think a system with GNU Bash installed also have a grep that supports PCRE.

Comment: No, MacOS for example has Bash out of the box but not GNU `grep`.  Earlier versions actually had the `-P` option from BSD `grep` but they removed it.

Answer (score 10):

Small and universal solution:

```
expr "$string" : "$prefix\(.*\)$suffix"
```

Comment: If you are using Bash, you should probably not be using `expr` at all. It was a *sort of* convenient kitchen sink utility back in the days of the original Bourne shell, but is now way past its best-before date.

Comment: Uh, why? `expr` is old, but never changes, and will probably always be available. As long as you invoke an external binary (as opposed to using BASH expressions), grep, sed or expr are pretty much equivalent (perl / awk would be costlier).

Comment: Fantastic, this is simplest, I've ever seen.

Answer (score 10):

Using the [`=~` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19441521/3180795):

```
$ string="hello-world"
$ prefix="hell"
$ suffix="ld"
$ [[ "$string" =~ ^$prefix(.*)$suffix$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
o-wor
```

Answer (score 8):

**NOTE:** Not sure if this was possible back in 2013 but it's certainly possible today (10 Oct 2021) so adding another option ...

---

Since we're dealing with known fixed length strings (`prefix` and `suffix`) we can use a `bash` substring to obtain the desired result with a single operation.

Inputs:

```
string="hello-world"
prefix="hell"
suffix="ld"
```

Plan:

- `bash` substring syntax: `${string:<start>:<length>}`
- skipping over `prefix="hell"` means our `<start>` will be `4`
- `<length>` will be total length of `string` (`${#string}`) minus the lengths of our fixed length strings (`4` for `hell` / `2` for `ld`)

This gives us:

```
$ echo "${string:4:(${#string}-4-2)}"
o-wor
```

**NOTE:** the parens can be removed and still obtain the same result

---

If the values of `prefix` and `suffix` are unknown, or could vary, we can still use this same operation but replace `4` and `2` with `${#prefix}` and `${#suffix}`, respectively:

```
$ echo "${string:${#prefix}:${#string}-${#prefix}-${#suffix}}"
o-wor
```

Comment: Great option! 

Worth calling out: a key difference between this solution and the others is that if the source string does not start with prefix or end with suffix, then other solutions will not clip anything, where this solution will clip the length of the suffix away.  

This is not necessarily a problem, just a limitation to be aware of. If you're not sure if the string starts or ends with the prefix/suffix, simply wrap this statement in the appropriate if-statement to check before trimming.

Answer (score 6):

Using @Adrian Frühwirth answer:

```
function strip {
    local STRING=${1#$"$2"}
    echo ${STRING%$"$2"}
}
```

use it like this

```
HELLO=":hello:"
HELLO=$(strip "$HELLO" ":")
echo $HELLO # hello
```