# Unix Shell Script: Remove common prefix from a variable

Tags: shell, unix, split

I have 2 variables one which is holding the prefix and other one the complete string.

For e.g

```
prefix="TEST_"
Str="TEST_FILENAME.xls"
```

I want the the Str to be compared against prefix and remove that common characters 'TEST_' and i want the output as FILENAME.xls. Please advise if it can be done with minimal lines of coding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove a fixed prefix/suffix from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash)

Comment: Since the question asks about a Unix shell script, duping against a Bash question doesn't seem right. Bash-specific answers, marked as such, seem appropriate here, but POSIX sh answers, IMO, would more closely answer the question as posed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using BASH you can do:

```
prefix="TEST_"
str="TEST_FILENAME.xls"
echo "${str#$prefix}"

FILENAME.xls
```

If not using BASH you can use `sed`:

```
sed "s/^$prefix//" <<< "$str"

FILENAME.xls
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ Str=$(echo $Str | sed "s/^${prefix}//")
$ echo $Str
FILENAME.xls
```

Or using awk:

```
$ echo $Str | awk -F $prefix '{print $2}'
FILENAME.xls
```