# How do I get two strings separated by a phrase in between?

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a string and its contents are `US1SERVLOC2`. I want to be able to get the strings `US1` and `LOC2` from that string.

```
echo "US1SERVLOC2" | cut -f1 -d 'SERV'
echo "US1SERVLOC2" | cut -f2 -d 'SERV'
```

I originally tried this but cut doesn't like delimiters that aren't single characters. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
s=US1SERVLOC2
echo ${s%SERV*}  # prints US1
echo ${s#*SERV}  # prints LOC2
```

See:

- Substring Removal section in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).
- This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/bash-remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string).

Note:

- `%SERV*` will cut `SERV*` from the end of `s`.
- `#*SERV` will cut `*SERV` from the start of `s`.
- If `SERV` appears multiple times, you can use `%%`/`##` instead of `%`/`#` to extend the matches. However, this will only allow you to cut at the first or last occurence of `SERV`. If that is not suitable, `awk` will gladly accept multi-character field separators:

  ```
  s=US1SERVLOC1US2SERVLOC2US3SERVLOC3
  echo $s | awk -F "SERV" '{print $2}'  # prints LOC1US2
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Use built-in shell [variable expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) operators.

```
var=US1SERVLOC2
part1=${var%SERV*}
part2=${var#*SERV}
```

However, these won't work the same as your attempted `cut` if `SERV` appears more than once in the string.