# Can anyone explain me about below exression

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am confused about the below regular expression I found in a shell script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
prog=${0%%.sh}-via.sh
```

Anyone give me a valuable information

Answer (score 4):

There are no regular expressions involved in that script.

`${0}` is the name of the called script.
The `%%` operator removes a matching suffix pattern., so `${0%%.sh}` is the name of the called script without the final ".sh".
Finally, `${0%%.sh}-via.sh` is the name of the called script without the final ".sh" and appending "-via.sh".

That value is assigned to variable `prog`.

Answer (score 2):

When you run a script, the variable `$0` is automatically set with the name of the script (which may or may not contain the folder, but I think this is not relevant to your question).

In bash the `${0}` syntax can be used to fetch the same variable, but in the braces you can add extra processing to the variable. In your example:

```
${0%%.sh}
```

will remove the ".sh" part at the end of the string, using [parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PCTPATREF).

```
prog=${0%%.sh}-via.sh
```

will add `-via.sh` at the end, and assign it to `prog`.

All in all, what it does is replacing the `.sh` by `-via.sh`. Let's say your script is called "myscript.sh", then `prog` will be assigned the value "myscript-via.sh".

As a side note, I would recommend starting your script with `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` because parameter substitution is a bash feature. More info about why it matters [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1133187/when-must-i-use-bin-bash-and-when-bin-sh).

Answer (score 1):

`${0%%.sh}` removes the suffix `.sh` from the variable `0` (it contains the name of the script) and appends `-via.sh`. The result is stored in `prog` which is `<script_name_without_extension>-via.sh`

For further reference see this related question: [Remove a fixed prefix/suffix from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash)