# Remove a part of string in bash

Tags: regex, bash

how do i remove `refs/heads/` part from `refs/heads/hotfix/sub_pag/105` and return the reamining part `hotfix/sub_page/105`?

Comment: The question is clear tbh, doesn’t deserver so many downvotes. But yea if so many people feel that, please specify that `refs/heads/` and the other two are strings or strings assigned to a variable.

Comment: @Mihir I think [this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stackoverflow+bash+remove+substring&t=ffsb&ia=web) explains the downvotes. That said, the proper course of action would be to close with a duplicate

Comment: @Aaron, agreed but at the same time its nice to write a short comment explaining reason of downvote. (would help viewers and the OP)

Comment: Also it's unclear whether the part to remove is always the same (in which case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash) is an appropriate duplicate) or the string must be removed up to the second slash, with varying words in between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cut`:

```
echo refs/heads/hotfix/sub_pag/105 | cut -d/ -f3-
```

- `-d` specifies the delimiter, `/` in this case
- `-f` specifies which columns (fields) to keep. We want everything from column 3 onwards.

Or, use variables and parameter substitution:

```
x=refs/heads/hotfix/sub_pag/105
echo ${x#refs/heads/}
```

- `#` removes the string from the beginning of the variable's value.

Comment: The answer doesn't involve any regex.

Comment: right. i did a quick google search on cut. bash has so many ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
abc="refs/heads/hotfix/sub_pag/105”
abc=${abc##refs/heads/}
```

The parameter expansion in the second line would remove that part.

Comment: Why `##` and not `#`?

Comment: @choroba, came out of habit. The match should be same in both the cases i guess because of fixed pattern. Is the latter faster?

Comment: If there's no wildcard, it's probably just shorter :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've found `sed` to be effective and obvious in purpose

```sh
sed 's/refs\/heads\///g'
```

Usage example

```sh
#!/bin/sh
long_ref="refs/heads/hotfix/sub_pag/105"  # normally from pipeline/Jenkins/etc.
echo "$long_ref"
short_ref=$(echo "$long_ref" | sed 's/refs\/heads\///g')
echo "$short_ref"
```

output

```
% sh test.sh
refs/heads/hotfix/sub_pag/105
hotfix/sub_pag/105
```