# rename files with suffix

Tags: bash, file, rename

I am trying to rename my file adding a letter at the end of the filename
This is what I have so far

```
suffix=x
for f in *.tif
do
    mv "$f" "$f$suffix.tif"
done
```

when it runs I get `001.tifx.tif`

How do I get the script to run and output `001x.tif` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove a fixed prefix/suffix from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash)

Comment: that would make it as easy as `for f in *.tif; do mv $f ${f%\.*}$suffix.${f#*\.}; done`

Comment: Thank you this worked. Now how can you add a sequential number to filename

Answer (score 0):

Like this (perl rename command) in a shell:

```
$ suffix=x
$ rename -n "s/\.tif$/$suffix$&/" *.tif
```

Remove `-n` switch when the result looks good.

## Output

```
rename(001.tif, 001x.tif)
rename(002.tif, 002x.tif)
rename(003.tif, 003x.tif)
```