# editing the name of a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

So basically i have a program that searches each file in a directory and creates a variable which consists of the name of the file and a number. The problem is that instead of creating the variable with the file's name and the number it also includes the extension of the file which i dont want.

Expected output:

```
./my_script.sh inputs outputs 1
InputFile=test1 NumThreads=1
OutputFile=test1-1.txt
```

My output:

```
./my_script.sh inputs outputs 1
InputFile=inputs/test1.txt NumThreads=1
OutputFile=inputs/test1.txt-1.txt
```

Program:

```
#!/bin/bash

Word1="${1}"
Word2="${2}"
Num="${3}"
for file in $(ls ${Word1}/*.txt)
do
    for i in $(seq 1 ${Num})
    do
        echo "InputFile="${file} "NumThreads="${i}
        out="${file}-${Num}".txt
        echo "OutputFile="${out}
    done
done
```

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I am not sure If I got you problem. For what ist Word2?
Maybe this link helps to cut parts of your output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already know the file extension, you can extract the filebase directly using [basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) as follow:

```sh
filebase=$(basename -- "$file" .txt)
```

and then return

```sh
out="${filebase}-${Num}".txt
```

If you don't know the extension, you can extract it first like that:

```sh
extension=".${file##*.}"
```

So you can extract the filebase in one line as follows:

```sh
filebase=$(basename -- "$file" .${file##*.})
```

You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1403489/627911) for ways to extract the different path parts.

The mysterious `${}` syntax which allows you to modify a variable is called [shell parameter extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: As you say, the extension is known, use the `${file%.txt}` form to strip it off, instead of relying on basename.