# Bash Recursively Remove Leading Underscore

Tags: bash, find

I'm attempting to recursively remove a leading underscore from some scss files.  Here's what I have.

```
find . -name '*.scss' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 bash -c 'mv "$0" `echo $0 | sed -e 's:^_*::'`'
```

When I'm in a specific directory this works perfectly:

```
for FILE in *.scss; do mv $FILE `echo $FILE | sed -e 's:^_*::'`; done
```

What am I doing wrong in the find?

Answer (score 1):

As the starting point is `.`, all paths that `find` prints start with a dot. Thus `^_*` doesn't match anything and `sed` returns its input unchanged.

I wouldn't bother with `sed` or `xargs` though.

The script below works with any `find` and `sh` that isn't terribly broken, and properly handles filenames with underscores in the middle as well.

```
find . -name '_*.scss' -exec sh -c '
for fp; do                # pathname
  fn=${fp##*/}            # filename
  fn=${fn#"${fn%%[!_]*}"} # filename w/o leading underscore(s)
  echo mv "$fp" "${fp%/*}/$fn"
done' sh {} +
```

A less portable but shorter and much cleaner alternative in bash looks like:

```
shopt -s globstar extglob nullglob

for fp in ./**/_*.scss; do
  echo mv "$fp" "${fp%/*}/${fp##*/+(_)}"
done
```

Drop `echo` if the output looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the syntax highlighting of the `sed` command. Single quotes can't be nested. Easiest fix: switch to double quotes.

```
find . -name '*.scss' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 bash -c 'mv "$0" `echo $0 | sed -e "s:^_*::"`'
```

I would recommend leaving `$0` as the program name and using `$1` for the first argument. That way if bash prints an error message it'll prefix it with `bash:`.

```
find . -name '*.scss' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 bash -c 'mv "$1" `echo "$1" | sed -e "s:^_*::"`' bash
```

You can also simplify this with [`find -exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find).

```
find . -name '*.scss' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" `echo "$1" | sed -e "s:^_*::"`' bash {} ';'
```

You could also let bash do the substitution with its `${var#prefix}` [prefix removal syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash):

```
find . -name '*.scss' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1#_}"' bash {} ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `find` at all (unless you are trying to do this with an ancient version of `bash`, such as what macOS ships):

```
shopt -s globstar extglob

for f in **/*.scss; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f##*(_)}"
done
```

`${f##...}` expands `f`, minus the longest prefix matching `...`. The extended pattern `*(_)` matches 0 or more `_`, analogous to the regular expression `_*`.