# extract hostname with parameter expansion in a single assignment

Tags: shell, posix, parameter-expansion

I am trying to get the hostname for a url. I am able to do it with 2 assignments but I want to do it in a single step.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

HELM_CHART=oci://foo.bar.io/ns/chart-name

host=${HELM_CHART#*//}
host=${host%%/*}

echo "$host"
# foo.bar.io
```

I am not able to figure out a pattern or combination of pattern to achieve this. I read that you can combine a pattern like shown here [Remove a fixed prefix/suffix from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash). I try all sorts of combinations, but I can't get it working.

Is it possible to do in a single assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with parameter expansion alone. You can with a regular expression match, though. In `bash`,

```
[[ $HELM_CHART =~ ://([^/]*)/ ]] && host=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

In POSIX shell,

```
host=$(expr "$HELM_CHART" :  '.*://\([^/]*\)/')
```

Comment: Thanks, ns is an unkown part though. It could be any url path. Ideally the protocol is also variable like `*://`

Comment: Updated. The `bash` regular expression can omit the protocol itself, and let the match start with the fixed string `://`. The `expr` regular expression is implicitly anchored to the start of the string, so you need to match everything that can proceed `://` as well.