# regex image name url

Tags: php

i want to change `:` to `_` like

```
<img src="http://domainname.com/image:name.jpg">
```

output

```
<img src="http://domainname.com/image_name.jpg">
```

I have this regex but it doesn't work:

```
$f1content = preg_replace('/\<img src="\/\/(.*\.jpg"|.jpeg"|.gif" |.png"|.jpg">|.jpeg">|.gif">|.png">)/','/1',$content)

$result = str_replace(':', '_', $f1content);
```

Comment: `:` is not regex, `/\:/` is regex

Comment: the second line with str_replace should be all that you need...

Comment: edit, update, how to replace image name  only

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to change from `image:name.jpg` to `image_name.jpg` you can use something like:

```
<?php
    $name = "image:name.jpg";

    $name = preg_replace('/\:/','_',$name);

    echo $name;
```

This will echo `image_name.jpg`

You can also use `str_replace` which should be faster then `preg_replace`, according to [this](http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=175031.0) entry. Which would be something like:

```
<?php
        $name = "image:name.jpg";

        $name = str_replace(':','_',$name);

        echo $name;
```

And this will also echo `image_name.jpg`

If you want to replace the whole URL maintaining the `:` in `http://....` you can use `\K`.

According to [Maroun Maroun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573989/3431018):

> `\K` tells the engine to pretend that the match attempt started at
>   this position.

With the following code:

```
<?php
    $name = '<img src="http://domainname.com/image:name.jpg">';

    $name = preg_replace('/[^http:]\K(:)/', '_', $name);

    echo $name;
```

It will echo `<img src="http://domainname.com/image_name.jpg">`. You can see a working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/lW2kK1/4).

Comment: how to change name only, without others name,, if i use this, output = http_domain.com/image_name.jpg