# grep exact value from string using regexp?

Tags: regex, grep

I am fooling around with some docker containers and I wonder how could I fetch password generated on container creation from logs.

So I run container with

```
$> docker container run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes -d mysql
```

This command starts a new mysql container with randomly generated password that I can get from logs. To be exact this command gives among others pass:

```
$> docker container logs mysql
...
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: Poow3eet2aat6aePhae6leipeecagife

2019-04-07T08:00:18.945238Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.15)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

That's just a background. Naturally, the important part is the line with `GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD` and you could assume I got this text file from any other source in fact. I'd like to store it in some variable with something like

```
export ROOT_PASS=$(expression)
```

To do so I need to come up with expression that would return only the random generated string. Of course, alternatively I could just assign matching substring of regexp pattern to variable.

I thought of

```
docker container logs mysql | grep -e "PASSWORD: .*"
```

but this results with entire line and highlights `PASSWORD: Poow3eet2aat6aePhae6leipeecagife` in fact. I also thought of something with sed:

```
docker container logs mysql | sed -e 's/PASSWORD: .*/$1/g'
```

... but this stripped the interesting part and returned everything else in fact.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append with GNU grep:

```
| grep -Po 'GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: \K.*'
```

or GNU sed:

```
| sed -n 's/^GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: //p'
```

Output:

```
Poow3eet2aat6aePhae6leipeecagife
```

---

See: [What does '\K' mean in this regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573920/what-does-k-mean-in-this-regex)