# Remove specific word nested in multiple html tags by regex

Tags: java, html, regex

I want to remove a specific word from html. I am processing the HTML as a String in java. The word must be nested in specific tags. I want to remove the `.wrapper`, only when it is inside `<template>` and `<style>`, I don't want to remove all `.wrappers` in html.

I have tried replacing the word with an empty string by regex, but it doesn't work as I need. I am missing something and cant figure out what.

String to process:

```
String input = "<div><template><div><style>.wrapper #popup-popupTemplate1 .popup-content { width: 800px; height: 300px }</style></div></template><div>"
```

Required output (removed specific word, .wrapper):

```
String output = "<div><template><div><style>#popup-popupTemplate1 .popup-content { width: 800px; height: 300px }</style></div></template><div>"
```

This doesnt work for me, but in online regex debugger, this regex select me required word.

```
String result = input.replaceAll("<template>.*?<style>.*?(\\.wrapper).*?<\\/style>.*?<\\/template>", "");
```

Comment: I assume that `replaceAll()` replaces your full match and not just the capture group in which `.wrapper` is located. Can you add the output you got by using your code to your question?

Comment: Instead of trying to do a single regex to rule them all, have you tried using JSoup or similar to walk down the DOM tree to the `<style>` element and then use a regex?

Answer (score 0):

- The "trick" is using `\K`.  [--> INFO <--](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573920/what-does-k-mean-in-this-regex)
- also deep dive into what lazy `?` does.

Regex: `<template>.*?<style>.*?\K\.wrapper`

https://regex101.com/r/ldnoFx/1

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work for me in code, but in online regex debugger you sent, it seems ok.

Comment: When I tested it in this online debugger, it doesn't work also. 
http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyEwsSBlJlY2lwZRiAgIC82rOLCgw/index.html
I noticed, that link you sent was configured for PHP, can it make that problem?

Comment: Does this work for you ? `(?!<template>.*?<style>.*?)\.wrapper`

Comment: This selects ```.wrapper``` even when it is not nested in ```<template></template>``` and ```<style></style>```

Comment: See if you can get PCRE in Java :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check way to replace the matched string (matched) from the original string (s1) with changed string (replacedString).

```
import java.util.regex.*;

    public class ReplaceExample { 

    public static void main(String args[]){  

    String s1 ="<div><template><div><style>.wrapper #popup-popupTemplate1 .popup-content { width: 800px; height: 300px }</style></div></template><div>"; 

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<template>(.*?)</template>");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);

    if (matcher.find())
    {
        String matched = matcher.group(1);
        String replacedString = matched.replaceAll("(.wrapper)+","");        
        System.out.println(replacedString); 
    } 

    }

    }
```