# Capture repeated letters in regex apart from the first letter matched

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm trying to get a regex that captures repeated letters except for the first letter that is matched.

I have a regex that gets the repeated letters: ([a-z])\1{2,}

However this would capture "ooo" in sooo. But i would only want to capture "oo"

(using this for the find and replace function in google sheets)

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: `([a-z])(\1+)` is this what you want? (just throw away the first capture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't mention what programming language or regex flavor you're using, I will provide multiple options:

1. **Use a capturing group:**

   ```
   ([a-z])(\1{2,})
   ```

   **[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fyT6hp/1)**.

   This will work with every regex flavor but your expected match would be in the second capturing group.
2. **If your regex flavor supports [Lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), use a positive Lookbehind:**

   ```
   (?<=([a-z]))\1{2,}
   ```

   **[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3HIrGb/1)**.
3. **If your regex flavor supports [`\K`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33573920/13485806), you can use the following:**

   ```
   ([a-z])\K\1{2,}
   ```

   **[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/06BN5K/1)**.

Note that `\1{2,}` means that you'll have a match only if the letter is repeated at least 3 times (e.g., `aaa`). If that's not what you intended and you want to have a match when the letter is repeated twice, you should use `\1+` instead.