# How do I find and replace a character when it is not one of the first 8 characters in the filename using prename?

Tags: regex, shell, find, rename

This will for example recursively find and replace all hyphens in all filenames with a single space:

```
find . -type f -name "*-*" -execdir prename 's/-/ /g' "{}" \;
```

how would I modify this to only replace hyphens that are not within the first 8 characters of the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pathnames passed to `prename` are prepended with `./` because of `-execdir` primary. So, you need to keep the first **ten** characters intact and substitute each dash with a space in the rest of the path string, which can be achieved fairly easily with a while loop (because `g` flag doesn't work when matches overlap) and PCRE's [zero-width positive lookbehind assertion thingy](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5CK)<sup>[*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573989/10248678)</sup>.

```
find -name '????????*-*' -type f -execdir prename -n '1 while s/.{10,}\K-/ /' {} +
```

This invokes `prename` at least once for each directory, and thus, may be slow due to overhead from initialization. If that is a concern, you can use `-exec` instead of `-execdir`, and adjust the Perl expression accordingly. Below is my amateur attempt at it, use with caution.

```
-exec prename -n '/(.*\/.{8})(.*)/; $_ = $1 . $2 =~ y/-/ /r' {} +
```

Drop `-n` if the output looks good.