# Using sed to extract a number value from json

Tags: sed

I have a file in which some lines contain a json object on a single line, and I want to extract the value of the `window_indicator` property.

A normal regular expression is: `"window_indicator":\s*([\-\d\.]+)` in which I want the value of the fist match group.
Here it is working perfectly well: https://regex101.com/r/w9Iuch/1

I've settled on `sed` because it seems that `grep` has to print the whole line and can't limit to the match group value, and `perl` is overkill.

Unfortunately, `sed` isn't actually capable of doing this, is it?

```
# sed 's/("window_indicator:)/\1/' in.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

# sed  -E 's/("window_indicator":)/\1/p' in.txt
prints out every line of the file

# sed  -rn 's/("window_indicator":)/\1/p' in.txt
prints the whole line

# sed  -rn 's/("window_indicator":)/\1/' in.txt
nothing
```

Comment: GNU grep is actually very good at this, `grep -oP '"window_indicator":\s*\K[-\d.]+' in.txt`. If you need the first match only, add `| head -1` after the command.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33573920/12859753 for more info on Wiktor's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`, you need to match the whole line, capture what you need, replace the whole match with Group 1 placeholder, and make sure you suppress the default line output and only print the new text after successful substitution:

```bash
sed -nE 's/.*"window_indicator":[[:space:]]*([-0-9.]+).*/\1/p' in.txt
```

If the first match is to be retrieved, add `q` to `q`uit:

```bash
sed -nE 's/.*"window_indicator":[[:space:]]*([-0-9.]+).*/\1/p;q' in.txt
```

Note that `\d` is not supported in POSIX regex, it is replaced with `0-9` range in the bracket expression here.

*Details*

- `n` - suppress default line output
- `E` - enables POSIX ERE flavor
- `.*"window_indicator":[[:space:]]*([-0-9.]+).*` - finds

  - `.*` - any text
  - `"window_indicator":`  - a fixed string
  - `[[:space:]]*` - zero or more whitespaces (GNU sed supports `\s`, too)
  - `([-0-9.]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits, `-` or `.`
  - `.*` - any text
- `\1` - replaces with Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result upon successful replacement
- `q` - quits processing the stream.

With GNU grep, it is even easier:

```bash
grep -oP '"window_indicator":\s*\K[-\d.]+' in.txt
```

To get the first match,

```bash
grep -oP '"window_indicator":\s*\K[-\d.]+' in.txt | head -1
```

Here,

- `o` - outputs matched texts only
- `P` - enables the PCRE regex engine
- `"window_indicator":\s*\K[-\d.]+` - matches
- `"window_indicator":` - a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - removes the text matched so far from the match value
- `[-\d.]+` - matches one or more `-`, `.` or digits.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Though its always advised to use json parsers like: `jq`. Simple explanation would  be, using `match` function of `awk` here, where using regex `"window_indicator":[0-9]+}` in it to match needed value. If regex is successfully matched then creating variable `val` which has sub-string of matched regex in current line. Then substituting `"window_indicator":` and `}` with NULL in val and printing val which will give needed value.

```
awk '
match($0,/"window_indicator":[0-9]+}/){
   val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
   gsub(/"window_indicator":|}/,"",val)
   print val
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` where using positive look ahead and positive look behind mechanism and getting the expected output as per requirement.

```
grep -oP '(?<="window_indicator":)\d+(?=})' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/.*window_indicator":([0-9]+).*/\1/' input_file
0
```

Using `grep`

```
$ grep -Po '.*window_indicator":\K\d+' input_file
0
```

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{match($0,/.*window_indicator":([0-9]+)/,arr);print arr[1]}' input_file
0
```